# Importing a python module/site-package (e.g. scipy) works from a script (a.py), but not from tkinter button command

Tags: python, button, tkinter, import

Importing a python site-package (e.g. 'scipy') works fine from a script test.py, but not from tkinter button command. When click the button, error shows：

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'**

test.py

```
import scipy
print ("hello world")
```

GUI.py

```
import sys
import os
import tkinter
top=tkinter.Tk()

def startCamera():
    os.system('python test.py')

B=tkinter.Button(top,text="hello",command= startCamera)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Both the test.py and GUI.py are in a same folder:
C:\Users\Breda\PycharmProjects\face_reg\face

scipy package in: C:\Users\Breda\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

sys.path variable contains:  C:\Users\Breda\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

I tried to import other site-packages in test.py and run via GUI button command , all face the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, but I am using the python3 packages coming with my linux distribution. Have you tried to add `print(sys.path)` in test.py? Because the problem might be that the path variable does not contain the same thing if you run the script with `os.system`.

Comment: in test.py you should put code in function - ie. `main()` - and then you csn import and run it `import test ; test.main()` and you can control it or get results from `main()`

Comment: @furas, i don't get it. The 'test.py' is a fresh file created by myself, not a python anaconda lib. U mean i need to import it in GUI.py?

Comment: @j_4321 print(sys.path) returns result also contains  C:\Users\Breda\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

Comment: You can import `test.py` instead of running it with `os.system` and then run the function you want in the button command. By the way, it is [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) to use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`.

Comment: I mean you can always import your own file like you import modules. If you put code in function then you can execute it every time you click button. If you don't put in function then it execute it automaticaly when you import it but only at first time. Second import of the same file doesn't run it.

Comment: @Frank if `sys.path` also contains ` C:\Users\Breda\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`,  I have no idea where your problem comes from.

Comment: @furas, well actually the problem is python thrown error when import site package (in this case scipy.py) in test.py.

Comment: @furas, if i delete "import scipy" , GUI.py run succesfully. So my question why via button command call test.py (in which import scipy) will give no module find error.

Comment: Do you have problem when you `import test` ? if `os.path` in `test.py` shows `C:\Users\Breda\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` when you run it form GUI or using `import` then I don't know why it can't find it.  Or maybe there is more info in full error message (Traceback)

Comment: @Frank: Perhaps do the following test: Insert `import sys; print(sys.executable)` at the top of `test.py` (before `import scipy`.) This will print the path to the python executable. Now try running `test.py` from the command line, and then by running `GUI.py`. My guess is that you will see two different paths. That, at least, might explain why Python is not able to find `scipy` -- the Python executable path that GUI.py returns probably is part of a python installation for which `scipy` has not been installed.

Comment: @unutbu, i think your comment make sense. Based on your input i did 2 senario:

Comment: @unutbu, i think your comment make sense. Based on your input i did 2 senario: 
1. execute both .py files separately in CMD, both files run succesfully without error, both python executables are same: 'C:\Users\Breda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe'

2. Compile GUI.py in Pycharm succesfully, but failed when click button . Error: "GUI.py python executable C:\Users\Breda\Anaconda3\python.exe. 
test.py python executable C:\Users\Breda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe.
。。。
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

Comment: @unutbu, so when compile in Pycharm, python executables of 'test.py' and 'GUI.py' are different. Does this cause the issue?

Comment: @Frank: Have you [set Pycharm's default Python](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#conda) to Anaconda's python3 executable? That might be one way to solve the problem. Note that j_4321 and furas also gave viable solutions -- I can explain further if you like, but let's see if we can get your original code working first.

Comment: @unutbu, after setup default python, it works. Thanks a lot! Also thanks j_4321 and furas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the `scipy` module could not be found is because the python executable run by `os.system` was not part of the python installation which had `scipy` installed. (There is more than one python distribution installed on this machine.)

The issue was diagnosed by putting

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

at the top of the `test.py` file (before `import scipy`). This prints the path to the python executable. Then `test.py` was run twice -- once from the command-line, and once through `GUI.py`. The two test runs printed different paths.

The problem was fixed by [setting Pycharm's default python executable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#conda) to the Anaconda Python3 installation which has the `scipy` module installed.